# how can I load a stylesheet with php if the page is not home?

Tags: php

I am trying to exclude a css file from the home page of my site. We load the stylesheet with the header.php, so I am trying to not load it in the homepage.

this is my following code.

```
$hm == 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($hm == "home.php") {
  echo "";
} else {
  echo "yesstylesheet.css";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this snippet

```
$hm = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$hm1 = strrev($hm);
$hm2 = substr($hm1, strpos($hm1, "/") + 1);
$hm3 = "/".$hm2;
$hm4 = str_replace($hm3,"",$hm1);
$hm = strrev($hm4);

if ($hm == "home.php") {
  echo "";
} else {
  echo "yesstylesheet.css";
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If do you mean home page - main page of your site, than you can try to use follow code

```
       if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!="/")
       {
          echo "connect ccs here";
       }
```

Comment: or provide what URL you mean as home page